# Declaring global exception in PL/SQL package

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, plsql, package

I have some procedures/functions in the package which catch the `-2291` exception when a FOREIGN KEY constraint is violated.

I removed the exception from the different procedures and declared it in the package body like so:

```
e_ouder_niet_gevonden EXCEPTION;
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(e_ouder_niet_gevonden,-2291);
```

Now when I use one of the procedures in the package there is no problem. What I would like to achieve, however, is that ANY procedure/function can use that exception. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: wait, you mean *any* procedure outside the package, not just the ones in the package?

Comment: yes, is that not possible? I thought it was rather weird as well, but it's part of an assignment I'm doing, so I figured it would be possible

Comment: Far as I know, that's not possible. You'll have to declare the exception everywhere, since you're asking Oracle to create a custom exception based on existing error.

Comment: if you found a solution, you should add it as a response, not edit the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SOLUTION:
Instead of putting the exception in the package body, you need to put in the package specification. If you then want to use the exception in a procedure outside of the package you can put this in the EXCEPTION block:

```
WHEN packagename.exception_name THEN
```

This works without problems.

Comment: If this is a solution then you should accept your own answer to indicate to others that it's been solved. I'd recommend if you're going down this route to have a separate package to hold your exceptions so that you don't have to remember which random package they're in.

Comment: Thanks for the tip re accepting my own solution. I can only accept it from tomorrow though apparently. And I agree that putting the exceptions in their own package would be much better, but this was just a little exercise in which it was alright to place it in the same package :-).

Comment: Hmm :) My (self-)deleted answer mentions putting it in package spec, but I didn't think it through to refer package_name.exception :) Neverethess, good stuff.